# Change via CSS the color of social menu icons

Tags: css, icon

my page is this [one](https://paubgood.com/) and I want to change the pinky color of the icons for another one. I have try several ways in here but I can't.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you tried several ways but you didn't provide information as to what they were.

You'll want to either add this code to your Custom CSS (customizer or Jetpack plugin):

```
.jetpack-social-navigation .icon{
    color:#000000;
}
```

With the little bit of information provided that's the best I can offer - will happily edit and add additional suggestions if you provide us with more details in your question.